# Do I need to check-in truststore and *.pem/*.cer files to my code repository?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have two files(truststore.*.internal and a *.pem) that I need to copy to docker image during build time. My understanding is the *.pem file contains the public key so I think it is ok to check-in to my code repository. The truststore file looks like a binary file and I think it is also ok to check-in. Is this correct understanding?

Answer (score 0):

File extensions (which do not exist in linux e.g.) don't necessarily have to say anything about the file content. Your pem file could contain a private key as well. You should make sure this is not the case before checking it in into a cvs.

Truststores usually hold third party certificates which are public by design so it is safe to check in.

Comment: The pem has the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`. So this must be a public key, since if it is a private key, it will contain `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`.  So will this be ok to check-in to code repository?

Comment: If no other section (rsa private key) is in there, yes.